# How to export image (png) containing black rectangle

Tags: react-native

I have Image, that I made with phone Camera. I need to make some censoring and place black rectangle into Image. I want to create png Image containing black rectangle, that I can send to Backend server. 
[image] I know [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)
but it only snaps whole display and result is in low resolution.

Is there some other way how to do it? I need to place rectangle into the original image source, not into display snapshot.

Comment: Can this rectangle be a div or image and centered to the image?

Comment: @BhavyaBharti Yes, sure.

Comment: If it is div or image position it by css.

'div{           
width: 40%;                 
height:40%;                     
position: absolute;                    
top:30%;                   
left:30%;                         
}'

Don't forget to add 'position: relative' to its parent element according to which it is been positioned.

Comment: @BhavyaBharti Excuse me, but I forget to mention, that I need to export result into the new Image.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: @AkshayRao I want to create png Image containing black rectangle, that I can send to Backend server.

Comment: Do you want to glue black rectangle and image together before uploading?

Comment: @BhavyaBharti Yes, exactly.

Comment: take a photo and save it as png: https://tutorialzine.com/2016/07/take-a-selfie-with-js                             

Here is the post of StackOverflow that may be helpful to glue two images.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655553/combining-two-images-into-one

Comment: @BhavyaBharti Yes, I know how to combine pictures. But I don't know, how to create picture from black View.